# How to disable SSL on Apache 2.4.18 running on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate

I have Apache 2.4.18 running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I want to stop SSL on that environment altogether. How can I disable it?

Here is what I done in attempt to disable it

In the `httpd.conf` file I commented out the following 2 lines

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

Also in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` I changed the `VirtualHost` port from `443` to `80`

I restarted Apache but now I can't get to my site. I get an error "unable to connect on all the sites"

What did I miss here? 
How can I correctly disable SSL on port 443 and run Apache without SSL on port 80?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have loads of mod_ssl config that now no longer works. Check your Apache error log for problems.

I'd imagine you have `SSLEngine On` config for your vhosts so that will need to go.

Also most installs I've seen had port 80 vhosts defined in httpd-vhosts.conf and port 443 config in httpd-ssl.conf but you seem to say you had 443 in httpd-vhosts?

Finally do you have a `Listen 80` config somewhere?